# files uploaded via google drive api are not visible on my Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I uploaded files to my drive app via api.
Files are uploaded successfully.
But cannot see them by logging in into my drive

Answer (score 1):

I can see all files uploaded by reading them via drive api list method. (of course using the same issuer)